# Magento showing top menu, search box and cart twice

Tags: magento

Magento is showing the top (categories) menu, search box and cart twice.

Click [Here is my site link](http://ibuytohelp.com/index.php/) This page shows  menu search box and cart twice.

It seems to me that the header.phtml is being executed twice

here is the header xml
i took this /app/design/frontend/default/buyshop/layout/ layout.xml

> topLinks

```
        <block type="buyshopconfig/navigation" name="buyshop.collapsedmenu" as="mobileMenu"
               template="page/html/mobilemenu.phtml"/>

        <block type="buyshopconfig/navigation" name="buyshop.advmenu.amazing" as="advMenuamazing"
               template="page/html/topmenu_amazing.phtml"/>



        <reference name="top.menu">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.topnav</name></action>
            <block type="buyshopconfig/navigation" name="catalog.topnav.menu" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
        </reference>


        <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" template="page/switch/currency.phtml"/>
        <action method="insert">
            <block_name_to_insert>top.links</block_name_to_insert>
            <sort_relative_to_other_childname/>
            <sort_before_or_after/>
            <alias>topLinks</alias>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <!--HEADER EOF-->

    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>topLinks</name>
        </action>
        <block type="buyshopconfig/navigation" name="leftmenu" as="leftmenu" template="page/html/leftmenu.phtml" before="-"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name="top.links">
        <block type="buyshopconfig/comparelink" name="compare_link"/>
        <action method="addLinkBlock">
            <blockName>compare_link</blockName>
        </action>
    </reference>

    <!--FOOTER-->
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" as="footer_newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <!--FOOTER EOF-->
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
</default>



<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
```

how i can solve this ?? please help me thanks

Comment: Hello enable Template path hints. Admin pannel: System->configuration->developer (way at the bottom of the page) 
Select the website or the store view you want to enable this.-> debug -> Template Path Hints

Comment: i just enabled. what should i do now ??

Comment: check front end you will know which template is repeated

Comment: i am new in magento.. can  you tell me how i can solve this properly please. 
here is my site address: http://ibuytohelp.com/index.php/

Comment: hello check cms home page in admin may be you add this div

Answer (score 1):

.visible-desktop {
  display: none !important;
}

it will work for you 
try this i just tested this in firebug for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this problem caused by this div -  . It contains this "second menu". Look through your project  with this combination id="spy". You fill find phtml or php file and than module for each this belongs. If you did not find it go to Admin->System->CMS and try to find this page or static block.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have worked on the same theme.
Just try changing the **bootstrap-responsive.css file line number 53** to this:

```
.visible-desktop {display: none !important}
```

Comment: if this answer workrd for you then you can mark it as correct answer.